# mount hangs when mounting unavailable network share during boot

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

I have following entry in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
192.168.0.11:/  /mnt/tmp    fuse.sshfs  rw,noauto,_netdev   0   0
```

then, I have following line in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
mount /mnt/tmp
```

This mounts the share at boot automatically. The problem is, when I boot while the remote host is down, mount hangs for a long time instead of giving up after few seconds.

Is there a way to fix this?

Where does the mount timeout come from? Can I change it?

If the remote host is down, I would like mount to skip after few seconds

Comment: Why did you even make the entry `noauto` and put an entry to mount it automatically?  I would remove the `noauto` and see if it behaves better, although I suspect the timeout is defined in the kernerl's filesystem layer.

Comment: Does your system use systemd?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - no, I am using SysVinit

Comment: @Julie Pelletier - I am using `noauto` and then mounting it manually myself, so that the shares are mounted later in the booting process, when my `/rc.local` script is executed. But anyways, that should be irrelevant to the problem I am having with timeouts.

Answer (score 4):

The timeout appears to be [hard-coded in `sshfs`](https://sources.debian.net/src/sshfs-fuse/2.8-1/sshfs.c/#L963) to one minute. To change that you'd need to patch and rebuild `sshfs`.

You could just mount the filesystem in parallel by adding `&` to your command in `/etc/rc.local`...

If you're running systemd, there are a [couple of ways](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) of adjusting the timeout for a mountpoint:

- you can add a `x-systemd.device-timeout=` to the options in `/etc/fstab`;
- you can create a systemd mount unit describing the mountpoint and specify the `Timeout` option there (the unit will take precedence over the mountpoint definition in `/etc/fstab`).

In both cases you'll need to remove the `noauto` option and the `mount` command in your `rc.local` so that the boot-time mount scripts can take care of things. You might find [automount units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) useful for this type of mountpoint.

Comment: using `noauto` and then mounting manually should be irrelevant. If I mount manually in `rc.local` script and it hangs, at least it hangs at the end of the booting process, when my system is up. If, on the other hand, I use `auto` in `/etc/fstab`, it hangs early in the boot process.

Comment: Removing `noauto` is only relevant if you want to let systemd take care of things, which isn't your case.